# Definition of non comparison sort?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, definition

I'm going through sorting algorithms. Radix sort is stated as an non comparison sort but it compares  digits in a number and sorts them. Can some one Please let me know what does non comparison sort actually mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort

Comment: It only counts as comparison if you compare two elements in the list. Looking at a number's last digit to figure out which bucket to put it into, doesn't compare two elements.

Comment: The formulations of radix sort I know of don't compare digits. They use the numeric values of the digits to access arrays.

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko @kevin Thank you . Kevin comment clears the confusion for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a theoretical Computer Science question and not programming question/issue.

Answer (score 8):

To my understanding, the differences between comparison and non-comparison sort algorithm are not whether there are comparisons in the algorithm, **but whether they use the internal character of the items to be sorted**.

A comparison sort algorithm sorts items by comparing values between each other. It can be applied to any sorting cases. And the best complexity is `O(n*log(n))` which can be proved mathematically.

A non-comparison sort algorithm uses the internal character of the values to be sorted. It can only be applied to some particular cases, and requires particular values. And the best complexity is probably better depending on cases, such as `O(n)`.

All sorting problem that can be sorted with non-comparison sort algorithm can be sorted with comparison sort algorithm, but not vice versa.

For Radix sort, it benefits from that the sorted items are numbers that can be reduced to digits. It cares about what the sorted items are. While the comparison sort algorithm only needs an order of items.

Answer (score 5):

A comparison sort algorithm compares pairs of the items being sorted and the output of each comparison is binary(i.e. `smaller than` or `not smaller than`). Radix sort considers the digits of the numbers in sequence and instead of comparing them, groups numbers in buckets with respect to the value of the digit(in a stable manner). Note that the digit is not compared to anything - it is simply put in a bucket corresponding to its value.

It is important to know why we care about comparison/non-comparison sort algorithms. If we use a comparison sort algorithm then on each comparison we will split the set of possible outcomes roughly in half(because the output is **binary**) thus the best complexity we can possibly have is `O(log(n!)) = O(n*log(n))`. This restriction does not hold for non-comparison sorts.

Comment: Is it correct to speak of best complexity in terms of Big-O notation ?

Comment: @brz between all upper functions O(f), nlogn is the lowest possible, so is correct.